# Why text editors deforms indentation of pasted code?

Tags: text, text-editor, copy-paste, paste

This seems to be very generic issue related with many different text editors (or maybe copy-paste mechanism in Windows?). Often when I copy-paste fragments of indented code I end up with the first line indented correctly and the rest of lines shifted right by one level and needing manual correction (which is irritating).

For example when I paste code:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < 5; ++i){
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

The effect often looks like:

```
int i = 0;
    for(; i < 5; ++i){
         System.out.println(i);
    }
```

This problems occurs even when using ultra-advanced IDEs like Eclipse. What is the cause of that problem and why have I had to deal with it for so many years?

Comment: You don't have this problem in vim/gvim when paste in paste mode http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2008/06/21/paste-mode-pasting-text-and-indenting-it-in-vim/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the cause of that problem

The IDE is probably trying to do some sort of *smart indenting* on your behalf, but in this case it does look like a bug.

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor does something very similar.

As an example of what I mean assume you copy this text to the clipboard:

```
System.out.println(i+1);
System.out.println(i+2);
System.out.println(i+3);
```

If you then paste that code into into your example in the location shown below:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < 5; ++i){
    System.out.println(i);
} <-- place cursor on this line
```

You should end up with this code (that is what Zeus does):

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < 5; ++i){
    System.out.println(i); < place cursor on this line
    System.out.println(i+1);
    System.out.println(i+2);
    System.out.println(i+3);
}
```

As you can see this is different from what you may have expected which is this:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < 5; ++i){
    System.out.println(i); < place cursor on this line
System.out.println(i+1);
System.out.println(i+2);
System.out.println(i+3);
}
```

That is *smart indenting* .

> why have I had to deal with it for so many years?

There should be an option in the IDE to turn off this feature. Zeus certainly has such an option.

Comment: Yeah, possibly it is in fact some kind of smart indenting. I will try to turn it off to be sure. Thank you!